# Data flow swapping schema name with table name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that calls a data flow in Azure, and I've had to rebuild it twice and the same thing has started happening again.  Somehow when the data flow runs its taking the parameter I created for the table name and using it for both the table name and the schema name.

The error I get is the following:

> Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'DeliveryFile': ERRORCODE:208, MESSAGE: Invalid object name '[DeliveryFile].[DeliveryFile]'.

What the sink activity should be targeting is `[MySchema].DeliveryFile]`

I've double and triple checked the parameters in both the pipeline and data flow and it's correct.

I've configured a parameter on the pipeline for both the schema and table names as seen below:
[image: Pipeline parameters]

Parameter settings applied to Data Flow activity in the pipeline:
[image: Parameters applied to Data Flow activity in the pipeline]

Sink transform Sink tab:
[image]

Sink transform Settings tab:
[image]

Sink transform Errors tab - I've also configured the error tab hoping to pick up a little extra detail on where this could be going wrong, but the "continue on error" option doesn't seem to be making any difference and nothing is ever written out to the storage folder:
[image]

Sink transform Mapping tab:
[image]

On the "data flow" activity in the pipeline I'm correctly referencing the parameters in the correct data flow parameters.

Data flow activity source:

```
{
    "name": "Ingest Shipment Event Recons",
    "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "dataflow": {
            "referenceName": "DEP_CES_DF_ShipmentEventRecons2",
            "type": "DataFlowReference",
            "parameters": {
                "StorageContainer": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.StorageContainer}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "StorageFolder": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.StorageFolder}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "FilenameWildcard": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.FilenameWildcard}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "StorageArchiveFolder": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.StorageArchiveFolder}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "PipelineRunId": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().RunId}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlSchema": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlSchema}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationFile": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationFile}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationDelivery": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationDelivery}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLoading": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLoading}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoard": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoard}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoardPreviousTrip": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoardPreviousTrip}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationVehicle": {
                    "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationVehicle}'",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            },
            "linkedServiceParameters": {
                "GetShipmentReconFiles": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "DeliveryConfirmationFile": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "ServerName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlServer",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "DatabaseName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlDatabase",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedDataLinkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Deliveries": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "ServerName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlServer",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "DatabaseName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlDatabase",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedDataLinkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Loadings": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "ServerName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlServer",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "DatabaseName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlDatabase",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedDataLinkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "LeftOnBoard": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "ServerName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlServer",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "DatabaseName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlDatabase",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedDataLinkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "LeftOnBoardPreviousTrip": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "ServerName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlServer",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "DatabaseName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlDatabase",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedDataLinkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Vehicles": {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "ServerName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlServer",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "DatabaseName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SqlDatabase",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedDataLinkedService": {
                        "StorageAccountName": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StorageAccount",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "staging": {
            "linkedService": {
                "referenceName": "StagingLinkedService",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference",
                "parameters": {
                    "LinkedServiceEndPoint": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.StagingLinkedServiceEndPoint",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            "folderPath": "dep-ces/logistics"
        },
        "compute": {
            "coreCount": 16,
            "computeType": "General"
        },
        "traceLevel": "Coarse"
    }
}
```

Debug run input (specifically the parameters):

```
{
    "dataflow": {
        "referenceName": "DEP_CES_DF_ShipmentEventRecons2",
        "type": "DataFlowReference",
        "parameters": {
            "StorageContainer": "'dep-ces'",
            "StorageFolder": "'logistics/raw/shipmentevents-recon'",
            "FilenameWildcard": "'esc-od-recon-T*.xml'",
            "StorageArchiveFolder": "'logistics/raw/shipmentvents-recon/archived'",
            "PipelineRunId": "'ac5670f4-1234-4b14-a59d-99a79eb7ac4b'",
            "SqlSchema": "'DEP_CES-edw'",
            "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationFile": "'FACT-DeliveryConfirmationFile'",
            "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationDelivery": "'FACT-DeliveryConfirmationDelivery'",
            "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLoading": "'FACT-DeliveryConfirmationLoading'",
            "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoard": "'FACT-DeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoard'",
            "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoardPreviousTrip": "'FACT-DeliveryConfirmationLeftOnBoardPreviousTrip'",
            "SqlTableDeliveryConfirmationVehicle": "'FACT-DeliveryConfirmationVehicle'"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be causing the data flow to use the table name parameter for both the schema and table names?

Comment: Is your table already created in target or you want to create it through the above dataflow?

Comment: Can you provide your dataflow JSON and dataflow activity JSON for better understanding?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I can provide the data flow json yes, but what did you mean by the activity Json?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula the table is already created in the target DB

Comment: Click on the Dataflow activity source code. https://i.imgur.com/EzoQfo9.png.

Comment: Also, what are the values for the parameters in the dataflow input? are those same? Check the dataflow input like this https://i.imgur.com/lT8bJhS.png

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I've added the data flow activity source as well as the debug run input values. I tried adding the data flow source itself, but it was too much code.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula anything else you need to be able to assist?

Comment: The error indicates the issue is on the Sink side, but none of the screenshots show the sink tab. Could you add that, please?

Comment: @SchmitzIT I've added additional screenshots of the data flow. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: @Jacques, I have tried your scenario and its working fine for me without any issues. Can you publish your pipeline and dataflow and debug it by reopening the ADF again?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I've attempted the publish route, that's actually where I spotted the problem for the first time before switching back to dev, running it in debug and getting the same result. This was after that same pipeline successfully ingested over 10000 files on the first run. After that I have no idea what went wrong.